# I can't run my winform application om startup?

Tags: winforms

I added :

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rkApp.SetValue("My Application", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

But my application doesn't run on startup , i also set :

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in app.manifest

And my Registry :

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.i]
Please help me !

Comment: Why does the path in the registry have mixed back- and forward-slashes?

Comment: i don't know :'v

Comment: The slashes in the registry value are wrong. You should debug the code that adds this key to the registry and fix the slashes

Answer (score 0):

Kinda weird when nobody has answered this question.

Application.ExecutablePath will return incorrect result in some cases, one of them is "#" sign in path.

Change

```
rkApp.SetValue("My Application", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

To

```
rkApp.SetValue("My Application", Application.StartupPath + @"\" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe");
```

Also remember to change all remaining paths if exist.